# Amplify PWM signal from 0-5V to 0-10V

Tags: pwm, converter, flyback

I'm trying to amplify my PWM signal from 0-5V to 0-10V. As the nature of my project is a flyback converter, I thought that using a logic level mosfet with gate inputs from Arduino was enough to switch it but I was proven wrong. I've got a pwm from china on the way but it is only able to go 0-5V 100khz. I've learn from the kind users here that the mosfet requires 0-10v for the mosfet to be able to do fast switching. Is anyone able to point me the right direction in pulling up the amplitude perhaps recommend a solution? I read about D amplifiers but I have a square wave output already. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a MOSFET gate driver, such as a [MCP14A0151](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005368A.pdf).

It is compatible with almost any logic ouput level (TTL, CMOS 5V, CMOS 3.3V), and ensure fast switching.

Of course you need a 10V power supply.

Comment: Hi @next-hack so it is ok if I just connect the output from my pwm to the mosfet driver that you mentioned and the subsequent output from the mosfet driver should be able to drive my flyback converter mosfet? My apologies, kinda new to all this. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes, you need just this :)  (remember to place a decoupling capacitor near the MOSFET driver!)

Comment: any suggestions for the value of the capacitor ? And this capacitor will be placed at the output am I right ?

Comment: No, the capacitor must be connected between VDD and GND. As Figure 4-2 of the linked datasheet shows, you should connect a 1uF capacitor in parallel to a 100nF one (By the way: ignore \$C_L\$. It just simulates the capacitive load of your MOSFET!).

Comment: Hi @next-hack. One more question if you don't mind, I saw 2 types of pins, input pin and enable pin. Any difference of connection from my PWM or do I have to connect the output of the PWM to both the pins? Thanks in advance !

Comment: According to datasheet, pull enable high (to 5V or even 10V, as long as the voltage is smaller than VDD and larger than 2V, it's ok). The PWM goes to the input pin.